# Convert unicode codepoint to string character in Ruby

Tags: ruby, string, unicode, utf-8

I have these values from a unicode database but I'm not sure how to translate them into the human readable form. What are these even called?

Here they are:

- `U+2B71F`
- `U+2A52D`
- `U+2A68F`
- `U+2A690`
- `U+2B72F`
- `U+2B4F7`
- `U+2B72B`

How can I convert these to there readable symbols?

Comment: @Gabriel I have no idea what you are trying to say about UCS-2?  It’s not a “Symbol encoding”.  It’s an obsolete serialization scheme that no longer works on Unicode, and hasn’t since Unicode 1.1, which is infinitely forever ago.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

How about:

```
# Using pack
puts ["2B71F".hex].pack("U")

# Using chr
puts (0x2B71F).chr(Encoding::UTF_8)
```

In Ruby 1.9+ you can also do:

```
puts "\u{2B71F}"
```

I.e. the `\u{}` escape sequence can be used to decode Unicode codepoints.

Comment: You could also just use a hex literal: `[0x2B71F].pack 'U'`.

Answer (score 19):

The unicode symbols like `U+2B71F` are referred to as a `codepoint`.

The unicode system defines a unique `codepoint` for each character in a multitude of world languages, scientific symbols, currencies etc. This character set is steadily growing.

For example, `U+221E` is infinity.

The `codepoints` are hexadecimal numbers. There is always exactly one number defined per character.

There are many ways to arrange this in memory. This is known as an `encoding` of which the common ones are `UTF-8` and `UTF-16`. The conversion to and fro is well defined.

Here you are most probably looking for converting the unicode `codepoint` to `UTF-8` characters.

```
codepoint = "U+2B71F"
```

You need to extract the hex part coming after `U+` and get only `2B71F`. This will be the first group capture. [See this](http://rubular.com/r/fXocVSS7ZS).

```
codepoint.to_s =~ /U\+([0-9a-fA-F]{4,5}|10[0-9a-fA-F]{4})$/
```

And you're UTF-8 character will be:

```
utf_8_character = [$1.hex].pack("U")
```

References:

1. [Convert Unicode codepoints to UTF-8 characters with Module#const_missing](http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/4546).
2. [Tim Bray on the goodness of unicode](http://www.tbray.org/ongoing/When/200x/2003/04/06/Unicode).
3. [Joel Spolsky - The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html).
4. [Dissecting the Unicode regular expression](http://rubular.com/r/fXocVSS7ZS)

Comment: `codepoint` was "U+2B71F". To extract just "2B71F" from it, I match it against a unicode regex. There is one group defined in the regex for extracting "2B71F". After the match, if there is one you can refer to it with $1 in this case. [Follow this rubular permalink to see the regex in action.](http://rubular.com/r/fXocVSS7ZS)

Comment: One of the best answers regarding unicode, utf-8 code points, character sets, encoding etc I have ever read on SO... and the links are brilliant.  http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html  is particularly spot on.