# How to convert a unicode string to its symbol characters in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, unicode, encoding

I have the following string:

```
Ruby :: \u041D\u043E\u0432\u0438\u043D\u0438
```

My question is how to convert it to utf8 characters (in my case cyrilic letters)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6976524/covert-unicode-value-to-its-symbol-in-ruby

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Ruby 1.9:

```
"\u041D\u043E\u0432\u0438\u043D\u0438".encode("UTF-8")
=> "Новини"
```