# Ruby on Rails adds additional Backslash to Unicodes read from another CSV

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, unicode

I have a CSV file which contains some unicode characters that I want to display on the screen.

Here is a screenshot to the unicode file.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/N0NnS.png

Here is my language_controller.rb that reads the CSV and converts it into JSON

```
class LanguagesController < ApplicationController

  def all
    availablelanguages = {
      :data => []
    }
    @language = Language.all.each do |eachlanguage|
       availablelanguages[:data] << {
         :id => eachlanguage.id,
         :name => eachlanguage.languagename,
         :csv => []
       }
    CSV.foreach(eachlanguage.path) do |row|
      availablelanguages[:data].each do |single|
        single[:csv] << {
          :keycode => row[0],
          :unicode => row[1],
          :chakra => row[2]
        }
      end
    end
    @data = JSON.pretty_generate(availablelanguages[:data])
  end
  render json: @data
end
```

end

This adds an additional backslash to the json so, \u091C becomes \u091C. Here is the screenshot to response in my devtools corresponding to the rendered json.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gWW0g.png

Because of this, unicodes are displayed as text on the screen and not read the way they should be. I know this is about character escaping. But can we have the JSON response to include single backslash instead of 2? How?

Please help.

Comment: What if you take the value of row[1] and transform it directly to the proper unicode character, instead saving the value as a string? I mean, if "/u0D15" means "ക", just put "ക" in the JSON structure

Comment: How can I achieve that?

Comment: Look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6976524/convert-unicode-codepoint-to-string-character-in-ruby

Comment: I don't think it is solving the problem