# How do convert strings like `"E1=90=A7"` into a character?

Tags: ruby, string, utf-8, character-encoding

I'm calling `to_s` on an object, and strings like `"E1=90=A7"` often appear. I [see](https://codepoints.net/U+1427) that it's the UTF-8 representation of `"ᐧ"`. How do I convert this to show `"ᐧ"` instead of `"E1=90=A7"`? `force_encoding('UTF-8')` doesn't seem to work.

Comment: What is the original object?

Comment: Looks like more than one thing going on here. Is the literal string "E1=90=A7" from the content of an email?

Comment: `["E1=90=A7".gsub("=", " ").hex].pack("U")` see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6976524/convert-unicode-codepoint-to-string-character-in-ruby

Comment: See, especially, @OcajNires' answer at the link given by bjhaid.