# gsub a backslash to display a unicode character

Tags: ruby, regex, unicode, backslash

I would like to `gsub` one of the backslahes in front of `u00E9` so that it will print the unicode character, which in this case would be `e` with an accent on top. Below is the code I am using, which doesn't work.

```
array1 = [
  ["V\\u00E9tiver (1978) ", "by L'Artisan Parfumeur", "12"],
  ["Time for Peace for Her (1999) ", "by Kenzo", "4"],
  ["Time for Peace for Him (1999) ", "by Kenzo", "7"], 
  [" Untitled (2009) ", "by Kenzo", "1"],
  [" Havana Vanille (2009) ", "by   L'Artisan Parfumeur", "10"]
]

array3 = array1.each do |s,a,r|
  puts s.gsub(/\\/,"")
end
```

so what I would like to know is the correct regex to get rid of one of the backslashes in the array.I was thinking that the one I have above would be enough.However it is not.

Comment: You totally got it the wrong way. removing a slash won't give you the unicode char. You should fix what gives you this escaped backslash.

Comment: Define "doesn't work"

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert unicode codepoint to string character in Ruby](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6976524/convert-unicode-codepoint-to-string-character-in-ruby)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to not understand how escape sequences work. Take this string, for example:

```
s = "V\u00E9tiver (1978)"
```

The `\u00e9` here is a representation of **one** character `é`, not a six-char string of `\ u 0 0 e 9`. So, if you try to replace any part of it (say, the "u"), you'll fail because there's no such character in the string.

```
s.gsub('u', 'U') # => "Vétiver (1978)"
```

Whereas in your string

```
s2 = "V\\u00E9tiver (1978) "
```

you have totally different situation. Here the backslash does not start a unicode escape sequence, but is instead escaped itself. Which means that the following characters `u00E9` are just regular characters in the string, not part of unicode codepoint definition.

Off the top of my head, I don't know of a way to turn "\\u00E9" into "\u00E9" (short of `eval`, of course). What you should do instead, is fix the source of that data, so that it does not double-escape sequences.

Comment: Yeah thanks for that so escape backslahes are not possible to remove by gsub...I will try to look into how this problem occured in the first place.