# How to convert "date de d\\u00e9part" into "date de départ"?

Tags: ruby, encoding, utf-8

I have strings displayed in irb with UTF8 codepoints, I'd like them to be displayed with- their "real" characters. For instance change `date de d\\u00e9part` into `date de départ`, or `\\u4f4f\\u6240` into `住所`.

Those strings are build by reading a file with `File.readlines("myfile.txt")`. `file -I myfile.txt` returns `myfile.txt: text/plain; charset=us-ascii`, and `"date de d\\u00e9part".encoding"` returns `#<Encoding:UTF-8>`.

Comment: Does `myfile.txt` actually contain the correct string? The double backslash and `charset=us-ascii` suggests that it contains `\u00e9` _literally_, i.e. the characters ``\``, `u`, `0`, `0`, `e`, and `9`.

Comment: `myfile.txt` does not contain the correct strings, it comes from a mongodb dump and contains literally sequences of characters like `\`, `u`, `0`, `0`, `e`, and `9`.

Comment: I suspect your dump is in JSON format. If so, perhaps you should read it as such (and use files named like "myfile.json" instead of "myfile.txt".)

Answer (score 0):

Was able to do that with `string.gsub(/\\u(....)/) { [$1.hex].pack("U") }`.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6976631/117704 was helpful.